# Code does not reflect on UI after button set visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

i have an update panel with Content Template in my aspx as follows.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Within the content template, I have 5 dropdowns with `AutoPostBack="true"`and a button which is a `PostBackTrigger`.

The dropdowns are sequential dependent on previous selection for binding.
After the 3rd dropdown has its index changed, the button will be set visible and the 4th dropdown bind.

However with the button set visible and 4th dropdown index changed (which should bind the next (5th dropdown), the user interface stopped working.

I did a step through, the code runs well however the 5th dropdown just doesn't get bind by the data. And the user interface works if the button just stay hidden, but i need it to be visible.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve it, by adding the 5th drop down as a PostBackTrigger.